# Header elements writing over itself

Tags: html, css, header

I always run into this CSS problem of header texts overwriting itself as seen below:

[image]

CSS:

```
h3{
  font-family: 'Girassol', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1px;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

html

```
  <h2 className="home-product-topic-h2">Our Products</h2>
    <h3 >
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
   </h3>
```

How can I get it to wrap properly?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `line-height:1px`:

```css
h3 {
  font-family: 'Girassol', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2 className="home-product-topic-h2">Our Products</h2>
<h3>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</h3>
```